# In Probability of 2 balls taken together from 9 balls. Why we multiply 2 if different color but not if the same color?

Tags: probability

> Probability of 2 balls taken together from 9 balls, 9 balls : 1 white, 3 red, 5 black.

Case 1 Probability of 2 red balls = $ \frac 13 \frac 14 $

Case 2 Probability of white and black = $\frac 19 \frac 58 * 2$

> Why we multiply by 2 if different color but not if the same color? In case 2, we dont take the position wheter get white first or black first, but we multiply the probability by 2.

Comment: Hint : to make a rigorous argument, you often need to talk of the first ball, and the second ball. In this case, red-red is identical to red-red, but red-white and white-red are two distinct possibilities.

Comment: You can also word this in a different way using binomial coefficients.  There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to pick two balls simultaneously (*order of selection not mattering*).  The number of those selections containing two red would be $\binom{3}{2}$, giving the probability as being $\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}$ which gives the same answer just written in a different way as what was given above.  As for the white and black (*or black and white*) that would be $\dfrac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}$, again equaling the same as what was given above just written in a different way.